# Problem Reading XML DOM Element using PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, xmlreader

I am failing!
Here is my problem.
I get a DOMElement
Code:

```
$ref_cell = $new_row->childNodes->item($j);
```

I access the properties of said element
Code:
e`cho $ref_cell->nodeValue;`
Computer says...
Quote:

```
Trying to get property of non-object...
```

I try
Code:

```
echo $ref_cell;
```

Computer says...
Quote:

```
Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string...
```

Can anybody explain this?

Any insight at all would be helpful - I'm about to rip my face off and put my the keyboard thru the monitor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the row is empty and has no child nodes.  I would start by checking to make sure each level of the Dom in question contains valid content.

Comment: here is the complete code + file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448542/unable-to-run-the-following-php-xml-reader-code

waiting for ur favorable reply. thanks